# TypeError: Cannot read property '<part of class name>' of undefined

Tags: sapui5, amd

I have tried to add the `InfoLabel` in SAPUI5

```js
new sap.tnt.InfoLabel({/*...*/);
```

But this error is repeating:

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'InfoLabel' of undefined

Comment: Did the below answer help? Feel free to comment there if something is not clear or missing. Otherwise please consider to accept the answer to let others know that the issue is resolved. See _[What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)_

Answer (score 0):

1. Make sure to **declare all dependent libraries**, to which the target modules belong, in `/sap.ui5/dependencies/libs` within `manifest.json`. For `sap.tnt.InfoLabel` for example:

   ```json
   "sap.ui5": {
     "dependencies": {
       "libs": {
         "sap.ui.core": {},
         "sap.m": {},
         "sap.tnt": {}
       }
     },
   ```

   <sup>Note: `manifest.json` is also called *[Descriptor for Applications, Components, and Libraries](https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/topic/be0cf40f61184b358b5faedaec98b2da)* or simply *app descriptor.*</sup>

   **If** there is no `manifest.json`, add the dependent libraries to `data-sap-ui-libs` in `index.html`:

   ```html
   <script id="sap-ui-bootstrap" src="..." data-sap-ui-libs="sap.ui.core,sap.m,sap.tnt">
   ```
2. Modules should be accessed **only after their dependent libs are preloaded.** This can be ensured using various APIs depending on the use case:

   - Declaratively using `sap/ui/core/ComponentSupport.js` **(Recommended)**:

     ```html
     <script id="sap-ui-bootstrap" src="..."
       data-sap-ui-async="true"
       data-sap-ui-resourceroots='{"my.demo": "./"}'
       data-sap-ui-oninit="module:sap/ui/core/ComponentSupport"
       ...
     ></script>
     <body class="sapUiBody" id="content">
       <div style="height: 100%;"
         data-sap-ui-component
         data-id="rootComponentContainer"
         data-name="my.demo"
         data-height="100%"
         data-settings='{ "id": "rootComponent" }'
       ></div>
     </body>
     ```

     <sup>Doc: [Declarative API for Initial Components](https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/topic/82a0fcecc3cb427c91469bc537ebdddf), Sample: https://embed.plnkr.co/16J1TFICxbqETCzaxuZ0</sup>
   - Using an inline-script (Only if there is no `manifest.json`; only for small demos):

     ```html
     <script id="sap-ui-bootstrap" src="..."
       data-sap-ui-libs="sap.ui.core, sap.m, sap.tnt"
       data-sap-ui-async="true"
       ...
     ></script>
     <script>
       sap.ui.getCore().attachInit(function() {
         // your code...
       });
     </script>
     <body class="sapUiBody" id="content"></body>
     ```

Additionally, avoid referencing controls via global names (e.g. `sap.tnt.…`)! Instead, require the modules accordingly:

```js
sap.ui.define([ // Dependency list; requiring the modules:
  "sap/ui/core/mvc/Controller",
  "sap/tnt/InfoLabel",
], function(Controller, InfoLabel) {
  "use strict";

  return Controller.extend("myController", {
    someMethod: function(/*...*/) {
      const myInfoLabel = new InfoLabel({/*...*/}); // without a global name
      // ...
    },
  });
    
});
```

From the [doc](https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/topic/493a15aa978d4fe9a67ea9407166eb01):

> [...] your application modules **have to** facilitate the concept for defining and handling of modules in UI5 that is aligned with the *asynchronous module definition* (AMD) standard.
>
> [...] All necessary module dependencies [...] **need to be handled by [`sap.ui.require`](https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/api/sap.ui#methods/sap.ui.require) or `sap.ui.define`.**

See also the topic *[Modules and Dependencies](https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/topic/91f23a736f4d1014b6dd926db0e91070).*

---

It's also important to always check if the target module is available in the UI5 version at all. For example, the [`sap.tnt.InfoLabel`](https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/api/sap.tnt.InfoLabel) was introduced in 1.54. You might get a 404-error if you're trying to require a module that doesn't exist yet.

[image: UI5 InfoLabel available since 1.54]

In order to see which UI5 version your app is running with, press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Left Alt</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd>.